# Using 32-bit ints and operands

Tags: python, int, bitwise-operators, bit

Is it possible to somehow override or overload the standard implementation of ints/numbers in python so that it acts like a 32-bit int.

```
a: int
a = 4076863488
>>> -218103808
```

Or is it possible to somehow define a variable that can't change type? Doing something like: `x: int`?
I want to do this because it's annoying to write `ctypes.c_int32(n)` on every bit operation and assignment. Especially since Python does not use 32 bits bitwise operands.

I know I'm basically trying to change the nature of the language. So maybe I'm asking what you would do if you had to do 32-bit stuff in python.

Comment: Changing the standard implementation or fixing type for a variable isn't possible (without heavily modifying Python's source code). Most bit operations (`& | ^`) work with Python's `int` very well without much difference to an `int32`.

Comment: `int`s in Python itself are variable length, but as @MichaelButscher correctly points out, you can generally ignore that and just don't put anything in one that requires more than 32-bits to represent.

Comment: so.. numpy or ctypes then maybe. It needs to overflow, im implementing c code to python (read trying)

Comment: The [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) and [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) modules may also be helpful, depending on exactly what you're doing. Also see the answers to the question [python 32-bit and 64-bit integer math with intentional overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745387/python-32-bit-and-64-bit-integer-math-with-intentional-overflow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some options:

- Use Cython. You can declare a native 32-bit int type there, and you even get the advantage that pure numerical code gets compiled to (very) fast C code.
- Use a `numpy` array of a single element: `np.zeros((1,), dtype=np.int32)`. Provided you only ever use in-place operations (`+=`, `*=`, etc.), this will work like a 32-bit int type. Do be aware that if you ever use a regular binary operator (e.g. `myint + 3`), you might be subjected to type promotion or conversion, and the result will no longer be `int32`.
- Use `ctypes.c_int32`. This comes built-in to Python, but supports no mathematical operations so you have to wrap and unwrap yourself (e.g. `newval = c_int32(v1.value + v2.value)`).
- Use a library like [`fixedint`](https://github.com/nneonneo/fixedint) (shameless plug), which provides fixed-integer classes that remain fixed size through operations rather than decaying to `int`. `fixedint` was specifically designed with fixed-width bitwise math in mind. In this case you would use `fixedint.Int32`.

Some less desirable options:

- `struct`: Throws errors if your input is out of range. You can work around this with `unpack('i', pack('I', val & 0xffffffff))[0]`, but that's really unwieldy.
- `array`: Throws errors if you try to store a value out of range. Harder to work around than `struct`.
- Manual bitmashing. With an unsigned 32-bit int, this is just a matter of adding `& 0xffffffff` a lot, which is not too bad. But, Python doesn't have any built-in way to wrap a value to a signed 32-bit int, so you'll have to write your own `int32` conversion function and wrap all your operations with it:

  ```
  def to_int32(val):
      val &= ((1<<32)-1)
      if val & (1<<31): val -= (1<<32)
      return val
  ```

Demonstrations of your options:

#### Cython

```
cpdef int munge(int val):
    cdef int x
    x = val * 32
    x += 0x7fffffff
    return x
```

Save as `int_test.pyx` and compile with `cythonize -a -i int_test.pyx`.

```
>>> import int_test
>>> int_test.munge(3)
-2147483553
```

#### NumPy

```
import numpy as np

def munge(val):
    x = val.copy()
    x *= 32
    x += 0x7fffffff
    return x

def to_int32(val):
    return np.array((val,), dtype=np.int32)

print(munge(to_int32(3)))
# prints [-2147483553]
```

#### ctypes

```
from ctypes import c_int32
def munge(val):
    x = c_int32(val.value * 32)
    x = c_int32(x.value + 0x7fffffff)
    return x

print(munge(c_int32(3)))
# prints c_int(-2147483553)
```

#### fixedint

```
import fixedint

def munge(val):
    x = val * 32
    x += 0x7fffffff
    return x

print(munge(fixedint.Int32(3)))
# prints -2147483553
```

Comment: Good list; you should add `ctypes` as it is available basically everywhere without installing anything extra.

Comment: objectnabb: `fixedint` is also available from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/fixedint/) which means it can easily be installed via `pip`.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very good list. I will have to check these out.

Comment: I am a little bit confuse  here.
` 
b = 4076863488  
        print(b)    
        print(ctypes.c_int32(b))    
        print(b & 0xffffffff)    
`    
outputs:
`4076863488
c_long(-218103808)    
4076863488    
`

Comment: @objectnabb `b` is unchanged by the call to `c_int32` - the middle print statement is printing a new object that has the signed 32-bit value of the original. Because `b` has bit 31 set, it is interpreted as a negative integer in 32 bit 2s complement.