# How to use 64-bit unsigned integer math in Python, respecting C overflow?

Tags: python, hash, integer, unsigned

I'm trying to implement the [djb2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) hash in Python.

Here it is in C:

```
/* djb2 hash http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html */

uint64_t djb2(size_t len, char const str[len]) {
    uint64_t hash = 5381;
    uint8_t c;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = str[i];
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }
    return hash;
}
```

And here's my attempt in Python:

```
from ctypes import c_uint64, c_byte, cast, POINTER

def djb2(string: str) -> c_uint64:
    hash = c_uint64(5381)
    raw_bytes = cast(string, POINTER(c_byte * len(string)))[0]
    for i in range(0, len(raw_bytes)):
        hash = c_uint64((((((hash.value << 5) & 0xffffffffffffffff) + hash.value) & 0xffffffffffffffff) + raw_bytes[i]) & 0xffffffffffffffff) # hash * 33 + c
    return hash
```

However, I'm getting different results between the two, which I suspect is because of different overflow behavior, or otherwise mathematical differences.

The reason for the masking in the python version was to attempt to force an overflow (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745422/371273)).

Comment: I would replace all `int` objects with the corresponding ctypes int object to start with. e.g. `5 ` and `0xffffffffffffffff` are Python `int` objects.

Comment: Can you give an example string that you get the wrong answer for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the algorithm being run by the C code very easily in pure Python, without needing any `ctypes` stuff. Just do it all with regular Python integers, and take a modulus at the end (the high bits won't effect the lower ones for the operations you're doing):

```
def djb2(string: bytes) -> int:  # note, use a bytestring for this, not a Unicode string!
    h = 5381
    for c in string:    # iterating over the bytestring directly gives integer values
        h = h * 33 + c  # use the computation from the C comments, but consider ^ instead of +
    return h % 2**64    # note you may actually want % 2**32, as this hash is often 32-bit
```

As I commented in the code, since this is an operation defined on bytestrings, you should use a `bytes` instance as the argument. Note that there are a bunch of different implementations of this algorithm. Some use use `^` (bitwise xor) instead of `+` in the step where you update the hash value, and it's often defined to use an `unsigned long` which was usually 32-bits instead of the explicitly 64-bit integer the C version in your question uses.

Comment: Thank you! In this case, I'm in control of both the C and Python implementations, so 64-bit is what I want, but that is an excellent point for anyone else who comes across this issue.

Comment: This implementation is very inefficient. It takes more than 2.5 minutes to calculate a hash of 1 MB bytestring on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

When calculating DJB2 hash in Python, you have to avoid using long arithmetic. For this purpose, you have to do `hash &= 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` after each iteration.

Here is a proper one-liner implementation of DJB2 in Python:

```
import functools, itertools
djb2 = lambda x: functools.reduce(lambda x,c: (x*33 + c) & ((1<<64)-1), itertools.chain([5381], x))
```

Notes:

- because Python is a scripting language, doing the `(x << 5) + x` instead of `x*33` is not more efficient
- `((1<<64)-1)` is just a short for `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`